# Access qt application as web page

Tags: qt, qt4, webserver

I have a qt main-window application from which several dialogs are accessed.

I implemented the server and client versions of the application using tcp/ip using c socket programming.

But now I have  been told to make the application accessible to any web browser after username and password have been given using QHttp or any appropriate class.

I'm a beginner and have no idea of implementing this. Could anyone give some tips or examples.

I'm using qt 4.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you. You have a Qt main window which contains some widgets arranged in a GUI. You want those same widgets to be accessible inside a web browser? Then you need to re-create all your GUI code in HTML, CSS and JS.

Your Qt app can use QHttp to listen for incoming client connections. When one of those comes, you reply with a webpage (written in HTML, CSS, JS). When this webpage is received by the user, his browser will display it. When the user interacts with the webpage, you'll probably want to send some data back to the Qt server eventually. You can do this either via [form posting](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/block/form.html) or via [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

You should know client-side web development is not that simple. Even when you know your languages, there's lots of things to learn about browser compatibility, security, accessiblity, JS app architecture, etc.

Comment: I was not clear right, sorry. I have a Mainwindow which contains buttons from which I can access Dialogs(not widgets, I was in a hurry). I need to view the main window and successively the dialogs on my browser. is it possible to do it using qt classes. Or should I use HTML or any other languages you've mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use HTML. (you can make your job easier by using a HTML widget library. I think YUI is such a library)

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your application into an Http server.  Here is an example using Qt to get you started:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservice-example-server.html

As Stefan notes, this means putting your GUI into HTML/CSS/JS and more.